# how can i check if a field is a textarea

Tags: django, templates, textarea, form-fields

I know about the form field method `is_checkbox` that is used to check if a field of a given django form is a checkbox or not. Is there any method to check if the field is a textarea?

i have tried doing this:

```
{% if field.is_textarea %}
```

but this does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like:

```
{% if field.widget...... %}
```

The widget is responsible for the rendering, not the field it self.

Example to check it in the shell:

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import widgets

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    text = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=widgets.Textarea)

f = ContactForm()
f.fields['text'].widget

<django.forms.widgets.Textarea object at 0x218ccd0>
```

Comment: is there a way i can check it in the shell ?

Comment: @Amyth yes, wait ill check something

Comment: Thanks @YardenST that works with modelforms too :), was helpful. But i wanted to check it in the templates and alternatively i have adjusted the css to take care of the problem. But your answer does fulfil my reqs. Thanks.

Comment: you can create  a filter that takes a form field and returns true if its widget is text area, this way you can do the check in the template

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: Explanation - the filter takes the field object and returns name of the widget used by Django which can be used in comparison to string.

Use define template filter in `templatetags.py`:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()


@register.filter('input_type')
def input_type(input):
return input.field.widget.__class__.__name__
```

And use it in template for example like this:

```
{% if field|input_type == 'Textarea' %}
<div class="col-xl-9">{{ field }}</div>
{% else %}
<div class="col-xl-3">{{ field }}</div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: While this might answer the question, some explanation of the code would be even more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same intention the only solution is to work with if condition on your `views.py`.
I mean first you give a name to your text area in the html code then move to `views.py.`
grab the name like this  assume your text area name is "text"
in views.py write this code `text = request.GET ['text']` then create the if statement like

```py
if text == '':
    return render(request, 'html page you want render')
else:
    return render(request, ' the exact page you want render if the textarea is filled ')
```